# Third Monitor on Asus z87 deluxe mobo

Tags: multiple-monitors, motherboard

I'm trying to add a third monitor to my setup.  I have an ASUS Z87 Deluxe motherboard with three outputs - HDMI, Display Port, and Mini-Display port.  I'm pretty sure it is supposed to work.  See their web site:  https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Z87DELUXE/

... however I can only get two of the three monitors working at the same time.

My mobo has an intel i7-4770 cpu.  (LGA1150)

My cable hook ups are as follows:
HDMI to HDMI monitor input -- 
Display port to HDMI Adapter then HDMI monitor input -- 
Mini-display port to HDMI Adapter then  HDMI monitor input. --

I'm waiting on a response from the ASUS tech guys, but thought I would ask on here to see if anyone knew of something I may be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the graphics hardware in the fourth-generation i7's doesn't support three independent monitors:

> #### Which Intel graphics and chipsets support three independent displays?
>
> Three independent displays are only supported for these Intel® Processors when used with an Intel® 7 Series Chipset Board:
>
> 3rd Generation Intel® Core™ Processors with Intel® HD Graphics 4000/2500
> Intel® Pentium® Processors 2000 series with Intel® HD Graphics
> Intel® Pentium® Processors G2100 series with Intel® HD Graphics

[Source](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-033714.htm)

Comment: I'm not sure that is accurate.  On this intel site:  http://ark.intel.com/products/75122/Intel-Core-i7-4770-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz?wapkw=i7-4770         ... it says "# of Displays Supported 3"